# AngularJS + HTML5 record audio file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, amazon-s3, audio-recording

I'm looking for a simple solution to record audio file and upload it to s3.

My web searches come up to find:

[WebRTC-Experiment](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC) which is the most popuplar solution i could find.

it also have a working example in the following link : https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

I also found [ngCamRecorder](https://github.com/imalhasaranga/ngCamRecorder) which wasn't supported by firefox yet.

I'm looking for a simple solution + working example, and suggestion.

1. Which solution is most popuplar to use with AngularJS?
2. if you can provide your own example or link to a working example that i can use.
3. if you also used S3 i would like to know how you can push the file to S3, and get the link to the controller.

The solution i found, throw error, and include a working example without the code itself explained.
I also would like to know how to push it to s3.

This is the code i implemented from the example:

```
$scope.start_recording = function()
{
    navigator.getUserMedia(session, function (mediaStream) {
        window.recordRTC = RecordRTC(MediaStream);
        recordRTC.startRecording();
    }, function(error){console.log(error)});
};

$scope.stop_recording = function()
{
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, function(mediaStream) {
        window.recordRTC = RecordRTC(MediaStream);
        recordRTC.startRecording();
    });
};
```

It simply throw an error:  undefined is not a function on recordrtc.js line 641

```
  if(!mediaStream.getAudioTracks().length) throw 'Your stream has no audio tracks.';
```

obviously mediaStrem is null.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There's an AngularJS wrapper for this, it's a simple directive that supports HTML5 (RecorderJS), Cordova Media and Flash.

Usage is straightforward

```
<ng-audio-recorder audio-model="someModel" auto-start="false">
   <!-- controls -->
   <button ng-click='recorder.startRecording()'>Start</button>
   <button ng-click='recorder.stopRecording()'>Stop</button>
</ng-audio-recorder>
```

You can see the full usage here:

https://github.com/logbon72/angular-recorder

Comment: Full Disclosure: I worked on this plugin, I forked it from another recording project.

Comment: The project I am working on is using npm with browserify instead of bower. How can I integrate this module with my app ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and figured it out. The function argument in the success function of navigation.getUserMedia() is supposed to be "MediaStream" instead of "mediaStream".